# Separate public ip addresses on host and guest with qemu-kvm

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Is there some way to completely separate the networking between host and guest?
I have a machine with one NIC, I can have multiple public IP addresses for that NIC. The machine runs a VM. One IP is for management and the other one should be the official public IP attached to the guest used for our clients.

SR-IOV would be the best separation but won't work in this case. 
Macvlan with passthrough would be the second best option but since there is only a single NIC it wont work either. I don't know if one of the other macvlan options would work?
If none of those would work, how would I separate the networks in the most secure way?

Comment: I suppose that you already study this option, but buying a second nic would be the simplest solution (avoiding deploy tricky network setup). Maybe the cheapest one also.

Comment: Create a bridge on host side and add host network interface and guest network interface to the bridge?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEEE 802.1Q VLAN tagging. Create a VLAN interface on the host and use a Linux bridge between the VLAN interface and the VM.